# How to generate uuid for each FastAPI request in a multiprocessing-safe way

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, fastapi, uuid

I'm building logging process for my API. For each request I wish to have unique ID and save this id with some other metadata.

I've come up with using `uuid.uuid5()` as my **request_id** generator, but now I need to do this in a multiprocessing-safe way (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Is there a solution for this?

P.S., my current solution is something like that:

```
@app.get("/search/", dependencies=[Depends(HTTPBearer())])
@authentication
async def search(
        request: Request,
        response: Response,
        #some more params here
) -> dict:
        #do actual computation
        ...
        request_id = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'python.org')
        #insert request_id to DB with other log info and add in to response json
        ...
        return result
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `uuid5`? Your current version will always generate the same identifier. Instead you can use uuid4 and get a random identifier each time. The risk of a collision is so small that I wouldn't spend much time thinking about it. If you need an even larger keyspace (not sure why you'd need that), [the `secrets` module has got you covered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) with `secrets.token_urlsafe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import os
import random
import uuid

uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, f'{uuid.uuid1()}{random.random()}{os.getpid()}').hex
```